# uisegment control tint color

Tags: ios, uisegmentedcontrol

Am changing the color of the selected segment. It works fine but uisegment control tint color is set to default until it is touched for the first time.

This is the method that changes the color for the selected segment. It works fine but when the segment shows up first time. It has pale gray color. Then when touched it starts working fine as I needed.

(This segment control is added as subview to uialertview)

```
 -(void)segmentValueChanged:(UISegmentedControl*)sender 
  {

        for (int i=0; i<[sender.subviews count]; i++)
        {
            if ([[sender.subviews objectAtIndex:i]isSelected] )
            {
                UIColor *tintcolor=[UIColor colorWithRed: 98/255.0 green:156/255.0 blue:247/255.0 alpha:1.0];
                [[sender.subviews objectAtIndex:i] setTintColor:tintcolor];

                trackType = sender.selectedSegmentIndex;
            }
            else{
                UIColor *tintcolor=[UIColor colorWithRed: 225/255.0 green:220/255.0 blue:210/255.0 alpha:1.0];
                [[sender.subviews objectAtIndex:i] setTintColor:tintcolor];
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: What are you doing to set the tint when the view is first created / shown?

Comment: [self segmentValueChanged:segControl]; I call this method at first. It triggers but nothings happens in changing tint color and Sorry I forgot to mention this Segment is added inside UIAlertview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself. Since alertview creates all the views only after [alertview show]. color changes to segmentcontrol is not afftected since segmentcontrol is not really created yet. So what I did was I delayed the process of segmentcontrol tintcolor changes until it's been created by alertview

`[alertview show];`

```
double delayInSeconds = 0.01;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(segmentValueChanged:) withObject:segControl waitUntilDone:YES];

});
```

Answer (score 4):

you can call `segmentControlValueChanged` method forcefully in **viewDidLoad** method. Like this:

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0.05 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self segmentedControlValueChanged:segmentedControlOne];
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you please change it from viewdidload or viewwillappear method of your view? because as per your code, it will change, when user first time touch it.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention this Segment is added inside UIAlertview. The other is added to main view and its inside viewdidappear and it works fine. The one which am having trouble is inside the alertview

Comment: You need to add its tint color whenever you are adding it to any views.

Answer (score 1):

truy this code

i solved my app in this code

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated

    {

        for(UIView *v in [self.view subviews] )
        {
            if([v isKindOfClass:[UISegmentedControl class]])
            {
               // ((UISegmentedControl*)v).enabled=NO;

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{

                    for (int i=0; i<[ ((UISegmentedControl*)v).subviews count]; i++)

                    {

                        if ([[((UISegmentedControl*)v).subviews objectAtIndex:i]isSelected] )

                        {

                            [[((UISegmentedControl*)v).subviews objectAtIndex:i] setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed: 0/255.0 green:176/255.0 blue:223/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
                            //[[((UISegmentedControl*)v).subviews objectAtIndex:0]setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                            //  break;

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            [[((UISegmentedControl*)v).subviews objectAtIndex:i] setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
                            //[[((UISegmentedControl*)v).subviews objectAtIndex:0]setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

                        }


                    }


                });

            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: thanks for your answers but sorry I didn't mention that it's inside alertview

Comment: Ya even I have no problem when it's uiview. This problem left me with no clue when it's inside uialertview